# Android regex always returning false

Tags: java, regex

I am having issues with regex always returning false even though 
"http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html" states it shouldn't.

I am entering all kinds of specials charaters "&$@R@," and b/b2 are both returning false in the logcat. The string I am putting into the edit text even displays in logcat as the exact one I input. Anyone have an idea as to why it won't match the alphanumeric characters?

Code:

```
    EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String et1Text = et1.getText().toString();
    int et1Length = et1.getText().toString().length();
    EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String et2Text = et2.getText().toString();
    int et2Length = et2.getText().toString().length();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\W");
    Log.d(TAG,et1Text);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(et1Text);
    boolean b = m.matches();
    if (b == true){
        Log.d(TAG,"True");
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG,"False");
    }
    Log.d(TAG,et2Text);
    Matcher m2 = p.matcher(et2Text);
    boolean b2 = m2.matches();
    if (b2 == true){
        Log.d(TAG,"True");
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG,"False");
    }

    if (et1Length < 4 | et1Length > 15 | et2Length < 4 | et2Length > 15){
        Log.d(TAG,"Length dialog");
        dialog(1);
    }

    if (b==true | b2==true){
        Log.d(TAG,"Special char dialog");
        dialog(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `matches()` which tries to match the whole string to pattern you can use `find()` which just tries to find any occurrence of the pattern. [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29)

Comment: First thing I tried that worked. Thank you. If anyone has any insight on to why I shouldn't use this syntax let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all an uppercase `W` matches any **non**-alphanumeric character. Secondly you only matches **one** single character. To match that the string only contains alphanumerical characters use the following regex:

```
String pattern = "[\\w]*";
```

Note that `\w` also matches underscore.

Comment: Where would I add that in the above code? It's a String and I'm reading patters need to be Pattern. Also yes, I am trying to make sure the whole string is alphanumeric only.

Comment: Where you construct your pattern you assign it a string: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\W");`. Just replace the "\\W" with the above mentioned string :)

Comment: This example you give is actually the exact opposite of what I was needing. Not in a bad way it will work if I (b==false |b2==false). It went ahead and went with the find(). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about android but this regex :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\W");
```

Will match any **non** alphanumeric character. If you would expand it, it would look like this :

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

If you want to match a single alphanumeric character including _ just use  :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w");
```

else use : `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]");`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regular express that **matches all alphanumeric characters** try `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`. If you want to **match all non alphanumeric characters in a string** try this `\\W*`

Comment: The square brackets in your second regex are redundant, and at least one of those backslashes has to go.  In "raw" form the regex would be `\W*`, and as a Java string literal, `"\\W*"`.  (But I think `+` is more appropriate than `*`.)

Answer (score 0):

The Matcher method, "matches", tries to match the Pattern against the entire region. The regular expression "\W" matches a SINGLE non-alphanumeric character. In other words, m.matches() will return true when you attempt to match it to a SINGLE special character. If you attempt to match it to  "&$@R@,", it will return false since the string contains more than just a single non-alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 0):

`\W` (or as a java string literal, `"\\W"`) matches one non-word character.  The `matches()` method implicitly anchors the match at both ends, as if you had really written `"\\A\\W\\z"`.  So you'll only get a match if the string consists of exactly *one* non-word character.  If you want to match **one or more** characters, you should change the regex to

```
"\\W+"
```